# Alternative `pdftk multistamp` to `pdftk` once it's no longer available?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, pdftk, gcj

I'm using `pdftk multistamp` on a server for adding custom page numbering, page headers and page footers to big (500-1200 pages) PDF files. I do this by counting number of pages in the input, creating suitable empty pages with page numbers, headers and footers using LaTeX and then use `pdftk multistamp` to combine the original PDF and the PDF with pages, headers and footers.

However, `pdftk` is based on `libgcj` (and `gcj`) and `gcj` is no longer maintained and has already been removed from GCC 7.1. As such, `pdftk` does not have any future as-is.

How to merge/combine PDF files in the future? I really would want to keep hyperlinks between pages working in resulting PDF files and metadata as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I started a Java port of pdftk a few months back; at this point it should have the same functionality as the C++ version but a lot more testing is needed. If you want to give it a try, check https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk and file a bug report when it breaks.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu 20.04 LTS has this packaged in the official repos.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue, and ultimately landed on using the [`combine_pdf`](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf) Ruby gem, which has a pretty simple API and works great. (Though I don't know how well it supports the hyperlinks and metadata you mention.) If that's an option for you, I'd highly recommend it. You should be good with a short script that looks something like this:

```
require "combine_pdf"
stamp_pages = CombinePDF.new(stamp_filename).pages
pdf = CombinePDF.new(base_filename)
pdf.pages.each_with_index do |page, index|
  page << stamp_pages[index > stamp_pages.size ? -1 : index]
end
pdf.save(output_filename)
```

Before that, I was using [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) (which requires [GhostScript](https://www.ghostscript.com) for PDF manipulation), but I was losing a lot of detail in the conversion from PDFs to images and back:

```
# Increase the `-density` number for higher quality.
# Add `+antialias` to stop ImageMagick from antialiasing your images.
convert -density 300 base_filename null: stamp_filename -compose multiply -layers composite output_filename
```